# How do I use the csquotes `autoquote` interface with tabular?

Tags: tables, errors, csquotes

The following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\openautoquote test & test\closeautoquote\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

gives the following error:

```
./tabu-csquotes.tex:7: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.7 \openautoquote test &
                        test\closeautoquote\\
```

I can, of course, achieve the desired output manually, with the following replacing line 7:

```
\initoquote\textooquote test & test\textcoquote\\
```

giving:

[image: Desired result]

but I feel like this kind of “low-level” workaround shouldn’t be necessary.

Is there some way to use the automatic facilities of `csquotes` while splitting the opening and closing quotations across the columns or rows of a `tabular`?

Comment: I don't think this would be at all easy and is not worth the effort, in my opinion. (Unless `csquotes` provides a special mechanism - check the manual - but I doubt it.) Really, if the opening quote is in one column and the closing one in the other, then there is something wrong with your code because it cannot be using semantic mark-up. You must be marking-up based on appearance.

Comment: @cfr: Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @lockstep It isn't much of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this would be at all easy. The contents of a cell constitutes a group, as far as I know. If, for example, you write

```
\bfseries a & b
```

then the `a`, but not the `b` will be in bold (unless something else affects the weight/width of the `b`).

Beyond this, it seems to me that it would be a bad idea to implement the desired functionality. If you have an opening quotation mark in one cell and the matching closing quotation mark in another, then there is something wrong with your code, because you must be using appearance mark-up rather than logical or semantic mark-up. Hence, it would be better by far to rethink the underlying approach causing the error.

However, more specific advice would require a bit more detail concerning why you want to use this construction, so that more logical alternatives could be suggested.

Comment: In a sense, my use case was such that appearance *was* semantics; I wanted to typeset what essentially amounted to glosses beneath corresponding words, surrounding each full “translation” in quotes.  I ended up just using the manual approach described in the question, but I'd still be interested in a more automated solution for future use.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame Then I suggest asking a new question about that with a suitable example. There are lots of specialist packages etc. for linguistics - perhaps one of those might help. But I don't think trying to use autoquotes in a tabular is the way to go. That is essentially appearance mark-up as far as I can see. (Is autoquoting even appropriate for this use? But assuming it is ...)